# Disable filtering for particular/some column

Tags: gridview, grid, shieldui

I have using ShieldUI grid in my project and in grid some column contain image and for that column I dont want to show filtering.Currently it will show for all column including image.So how can I hide it for image column and show non image column.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable filtering for a particular column, you will need to set `filterable: false` for it.

More info can be found on the [Grid documentation page](https://www.shieldui.com/documentation/grid/javascript/api/settings/columns/filterable).